# CreateSalesforceObject function call failure

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

i try to create a new record with AMPscript on a custom salescloud object but i still got an error message. No matter what I try.
Marketing Cloud Connector and Imports from the SC to the MC works fine.

My (simple) AMPscript looks like this:

```
%%[ 
  var @id 
  Set @id=CreateSalesforceObject("ABC_CustomObject__c", 4, 
  "Name", "Test", 
  "ABC_GCode__c", "TestCode", 
  "ABC_Gtype__c", "String", 
  "ABC_Gwert__c", "6")  
]%%
```

SF Salescloud object field name and data type informations:

```
Fields from the AMPscript:
Name            -> Text(80) (Required Field)(Indexed)
ABC_GCode__c    -> Text(50)
ABC_Gtype__c    -> Picklist (value is in the picklist)
ABC_Gwert__c    -> Currency(5, 2)   

Other fields:
CreatedBy       -> Lookup(User)
LastModifiedBy  -> Lookup(User)
Owner           -> Lookup(User,Queue)(Indexed)
ABC_Adatum__c   -> Date
ABC_BTyp__c     -> Picklist
ABC_G__c        -> Date
ABC_GNummer__c  -> Text(80)(External ID)(Indexed)
ABC_GNutzer__c  -> Lookup(Contact)(Indexed)
ABC_Campaign__c -> Lookup(Campaign)(Indexed)
ABC_PlatzId__c  -> Text(20)
ABC_Sorte__c    -> Lookup(Sorte)(Indexed)
ABC_Status__c   -> Picklist
```

The manually creation of a record on the object works in the salescloud with the (MC Connector) user.

Does anyone have an idea? Do you maybe need more informations? I am very grateful for any help!

Regards 
Pat

Here you see the error message from sf support:

```
ExactTarget.OMM.FunctionExecutionException: Call to create the salesforceobject ABC_CustomObject__c failed! Error in the application.
Error Code: CREATESFOJBECT_FUNC_ERROR
- from SalesforceFunctionHandler

--- Stack Trace ---

at ExactTarget.Integration.Salesforce.SalesforceFunctionHandler.CreateSalesforceObject(ResolvedFunction resolvedFunction, FunctionInvokeContext invokeContext, FunctionReturnInformation& returnInfo)
at ExactTarget.Integration.Salesforce.SalesforceFunctionHandler.Invoke(ResolvedFunction resolvedFunction, FunctionInvokeContext invokeContext, FunctionReturnInformation& returnInfo)
at ExactTarget.OMM.ResolvedFunction.Invoke(FunctionInvokeContext invokeContext, FunctionReturnInformation& returnInfo)
at ExactTarget.OMM.ScriptExpression.GetTypedValue(SlotData slotData, SubscriberData subData, FunctionReturnInformation& returnInfo)
at ExactTarget.OMM.ScriptVariableSet.GetContent(SubscriberData subscriberData, Boolean performSubstititions, Boolean skipNewURLWrapping, StringBuilder outputSB)
at ExactTarget.OMM.EmailScriptBlock.GetContent(SubscriberData subscriberData, Boolean performSubstititions, Boolean skipNewURLWrapping, StringBuilder outputSB)
at ExactTarget.OMM.SubscriberEmailBodyBuilder.GetEmailBody(SubscriberData subscriberData, Boolean performSubstititions, Boolean skipNewURLWrapping, EmailContentCollection contentCollection, StringBuilder outputSB)
at ExactTarget.OMM.SubscriberEmailBodyBuilder.GetTextBody(SubscriberData subscriberData, Boolean performSubstititions, Boolean skipNewURLWrapping, StringBuilder outputSB)
at ExactTarget.OMM.SubscriberEmailBuilder.BuildEmail(SubscriberEmailBodyBuilder bodyBuilder, SubscriberData subscriberData)
at ExactTarget.OMM.SubscriberEmailBuilder.BuildEmail(SubscriberData subscriberData, Boolean returnEmptySubscriberMessageForExcludedSubscriber)
at OMM.MessageBuilder.BuildMessages(SubscriberDataBatchSegment subscriberDataBatchSegment)
at OMM.MessageBuildManager.SendToSubscribers(SubscriberDataBatchCollection subscriberDataBatchCollection, Boolean& workFound)
at OMM.OMMSlot.SendEmail()
at OMM.OMMSlot.Process()
```

Comment: Please update your question with details about the `ABC_CustomObject__c`.  Are there constraints or data types you need to consider when creating an object of this type in SF?

Comment: Hi, i add all details from the object. If i forget something, i will update the question once again...

Comment: try to add both the Date fields in AmpScript and execute your code.

Comment: Helpful error!! One possibility might be type conversion from String to Currency. Could you try "ABC_Gwert__c", "6.00"?

Comment: Hi Macca, 
thank you for your answer and solution. The problem was on this value. Now the creation of a salesforce record works fine. :-)